# Increase css width in percent with slide ui

Tags: jquery, uislider

I'm looking to increase the width of a div using Jquery and it's ui slide function. I'd like this to be done by using the handler.

The div's width and height are initially set in percent and I'd like to increase width by 5% on each slide step.

This is what I currently have. If I set the css within the function to be just 10, instead of '10%' the slide works but uses pixels instead of percent. How can I achieve this same effect using percent.

HTML

```
 <div id="slider"></div>
    <div id="boxout">
       <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 #slider {
width: 200px;
margin: 50px auto;
}

#boxout {

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#box {

  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({    
        min:0, max: 5,
        slide: function(event,ui){
            $("#box").css('width','10%'*(1+(ui.value)));

        },
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yq3ocs47/

Many thanks

Comment: you are trying to multiply string with number `'10%'*(1+(ui.value))` that wouldnt help you, you should use `$("#box").css('width',10*(1+(ui.value))+'%');` and check it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({    
        min:0, max: 20,
        slide: function(event,ui){
            $("#box").css('width',(ui.value*5) + '%');
        },
    });
});
```

I guess this is what you wanted, basically if you want it to grow `5%` you need to have `20 steps`. `100/20 = 5`

So you take the `ui.value` and time it by `5`, so you have `[0,5,10,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]`

Comment: say if it's width was currently 97% and I wanted to increment by 2% each step, how would this be done? Ensuring that the lowest value on the slider must be 97%

Comment: So you want 97-99?

min: 0, max: 1, (97+(ui.value*2)) + '%'

Comment: Hi Pavlo, sorry, I wasnt clear in my initial question (just trying to simplify it!) However, I'd want to go upto 117 in as many steps as possible

Comment: You want to go from `0-117` or `97-117`, and may i ask the reason why? When you go over `100%` it stop making sense. If it is `97-117`, then you can just use the initial code i gave you, then use a variable for the data to show the user like `var displayValue = ui.value + 97;`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply a string with a number. You just need to adjust that line:

`$("#box").css('width', 10*(1+(ui.value)) + "%");`